# how to lock linux user account after certain unsuccessful attempts

Tags: redhat

How to lock user account on Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 5.7 after certain no of unsuccessful attempts

Answer (score 3):

Use the [pam_tally](http://linux.die.net/man/8/pam_tally) module in your PAM authentication setup. Insert as desired into the relevant `/etc/pam.d/*` configuration files.

Sample:

```
auth     required       pam_tally.so deny=10 unlock_time=60 per_user
```

10 failed logins generates a 1 minute lockout.

Comment: which pam config file I need to insert this line?? is it /etc/pam.d/system-auth